# Why was my comment flag "Too chatty" declined?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, declined-flags, comment-flags

I flagged one of [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510923/comare-between-two-columns-and-subtract#comment25481149_17510923) but my flag was declined.

In my honest opinion, a repeated comment (esp. from the same user) on the same question is "too chatty".

I believe that I could flag all 3 of them, or flag one with a custom message that tells the mod that this is too chatty if you take the other 2 comments as well, but I believe this is something that you have to check anyway if a comment is flagged as "too chatty".

I could also use the "not constructive" flag (It does not add extra value), but "too chatty" fits also well, because it just tells in a very high noise/value ratio that the OP needs some help.

Comment: I deleted the second two just now because you're obviously right - three identical comments are noise.  I left the first one because it's a response to the prior comments by others.

Comment: The meta effect. Why do we need flags if they are declined anyway? :P

Comment: "Too chatty" is in fact a typo, it's meant to say "Too catty" and should be used to flag users who use a picture of a cat as there profile image... It's all right there in the handbook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flags for comments/posts are shown out of context with just that comment/post.  If it's not clear from just that comment alone that the flag applies you should be using a custom flag that gives the moderator/high rep user handling the flag enough information to know that they should check the question, i.e. if the flag is a custom reason that reason says, "asking the same question 3 times" then they know that they need to go to the question and see if they did indeed ask the same question 3 times.

Comment: Ohh, ok. As you might read between the lines, I had the impression that the context is there. I'll accept this.